# grunt server error in npm even after grunt install successful

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm, grunt-contrib-watch

I need to run the grunt server command..
but the problem is i am getting the error..
i even installed grunt by using this command npm install grunt and it was successful 
but i am still getting the error..when i do **grunt serve**r..
can you tell me how to fix it

```
 grunt sever
Warning: Task "sever" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-03-18 02:16:16 UTC)
loading tasks  1.9s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 100%
Total 1.9s
```

Comment: Well, are you running `grunt server` or `grunt sever`?

Comment: Can you include the content of your `Gruntfile.js` as this will show if you have either a `serve` or `server` task defined.

Comment: You need to install the grunt server task via NPM as well.